# Json parse error using POST in django rest api

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a simple GET/POST api via Django REST framework

`views.py`

```
class cuser(APIView):
def post(self, request):
   stream  = BytesIO(request.DATA)
    json = JSONParser().parse(stream)
    return Response()
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',

           url(r'^challenges/',views.getall.as_view() ),
           url(r'^cuser/' , views.cuser.as_view() ),
      )
```

I am trying to `POST` some json to `/api/cuser/` (api is namespace in my project's `urls.py` ) ,
the `JSON`

```
{
"username" : "abhishek",
"email" : "john@doe.com",
"password" : "secretpass"
}
```

I tried from both Browseable API page and `httpie` ( A python made tool similar to curl)

`httpie command`

```
http --json POST http://localhost:58601/api/cuser/ username=abhishek email=john@doe.com password=secretpass
```

but I am getting JSON parse error :

```
JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

`Whole Debug message using --verbose --debug`

```
    POST /api/cuser/ HTTP/1.1

Content-Length: 75

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Host: localhost:55392

Accept: application/json

User-Agent: HTTPie/0.8.0

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8



{"username": "abhishek", "email": "john@doe.com", "password": "aaezaakmi1"}

HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST

Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 09:40:03 GMT

Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.9

Vary: Accept, Cookie

Content-Type: application/json

Allow: POST, OPTIONS



{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}
```

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you are posting that JSON. Where from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Tried both `httpie` and from browseable api page

Comment: Try adding `--verbose --debug` to the HTTPie command. That will show you the request that is being sent as well as some additional debug output.

Comment: @JakubRoztočil added debug output , although I can't make much from it

Comment: I think there is some bug on the server side. The request/JSON looks correct. You can also try to send the same request to `httpbin.org` and see how it gets interpreted:  `$  http --json httpbin.org/post username=abhishek email=john@doe.com password=secretpass`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem that you are running into is that your request is already being parsed, and you are trying to parse it a second time.

From ["How the parser is determined"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#how-the-parser-is-determined)

> The set of valid parsers for a view is always defined as a list of classes. When `request.data` is accessed, REST framework will examine the Content-Type header on the incoming request, and determine which parser to use to parse the request content.

In your code you are accessing `request.DATA`, which is the 2.4.x equaivalent of `request.data`. So your request is being parsed as soon as you call that, and `request.DATA` is actually returning the dictionary that you were expecting to parse.

```
json = request.DATA
```

is really all you need to parse the incoming JSON data. You were really passing a Python dictionary into `json.loads`, which does not appear to be able to parse it, and that is why you were getting your error.

Comment: is the data is auto-rendered to json when sending back too?

Comment: If you use the custom response class, yes.

Answer (score 14):

I arrived at this post via Google for

> "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double-quotes": 
>   Turns out you CANNOT have a **trailing comma** in JSON.

So if you are getting this error you may need to change a post like this:

```
{
    "username" : "abhishek",
    "email" : "john@doe.com",
    "password" : "secretpass",
}
```

to this:

```
{
    "username" : "abhishek",
    "email" : "john@doe.com",
    "password" : "secretpass"
}
```

Note the removed **comma** after the last property in the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, whenever you are trying to make a post request with requests lib, This library also contains json argument which is ignored in the case when data argument is set to files or data. So basically when **json** argument is set with json data. Headers are set as`Content-Type: application/json`. **Json** argument basically **encodes data** sends into a **json** format. So that at DRF particularly is able to **parse json** data. Else in case of only data argument it is been treated as form-encoded

`requests.post(url, json={"key1":"value1"})`

you can find more here [request.post complicated post methods](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)