# "<field>":["This field is required."] message Django REST framework

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, request

so today I have been trying to implement the Django REST framework for the first time to my project, everything has been working fine I can create, update, and delete post using the browser interface that the framework provides, but after integrating the JWT token and trying to create a post using curl I always get  the message "":["This field is required."] . I have tried to troubleshoot it in many ways but there is no way to parse the fields that I need to correctly. I even was able to create a Post using curl but I had to modify the fields to be all "nulls". Am I sending a wrong curl request ?

curl: (note that if I add -H "Content-Type: application/json" I get this output `{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}` that has been already solved here [Json parse error using POST in django rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114514/json-parse-error-using-post-in-django-rest-api/48430011) by removing the content-type header) **edit:** ignore what I just said it needs to have the content type header, it was a misunderstanding of my part

```
 curl -X POST -H  "Authorization: JWT <token>" -d '{
                    "title": "Helloooo",
                    "content": "Hi",
                    "schools": null,
                    "course": null,
                    "classes": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "isbn": 12312,
                    "semester": null,
                    "visible": false

}' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/create/?type=post'
```

This is the output that I get from the terminal after sending the POST request:

```
 {"title":["This field is required."],"content":["This field is required."],"classes":["This list may not be empty."]}
```

Here is the rest of my code:

Serializers:

```
class PostCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    date_posted = serializers.HiddenField(default=timezone.now)

 class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
 "title",
 "content",
 "schools",
 "course",
 "classes",
 "isbn",
 "semester",
 "visible",
 "date_posted",
        ]
```

Views:

```
class PostCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateSerializer

 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r"", PostListAPIView.as_view(), name="List-API"),
    path("create/", PostCreateAPIView.as_view(), name="Create-API") ]
```

Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer", 
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication", 
        "rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"  
    ],
}
```

Thanks for taking your time to read though all this !

Comment: This problem is probably in windows. Is it true?

Comment: do you mean the OS windows ? yes I am using powershell 7  to make the request

Comment: I edited my answer. Problem is in using single quotes for body in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is in your request with **curl**.
I recommend to use **Postman** instead.
But if you want to use **curl**, for sending body with JSON content type, you have to determine it in request header.
In Windows OS, you can't determine JSON body using single quotes.
So try this instead:

```bash
curl -X POST \
-H  "Authorization: JWT <token>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{
                    \"title\": \"Helloooo\",
                    \"content\": \"Hi\",
                    \"schools\": null,
                    \"course\": null,
                    \"classes\": [
                        1
                    ],
                    \"isbn\": 12312,
                    \"semester\": null,
                    \"visible\": false

}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/create/?type=post
```

Comment: thanks ! I have solved my problem, posted a comment clarifying everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Seyyed Sajjad Sanikhani I have solved my problem in the end I actually needed to specify the content type by using the right quotes and padding in powershell, the final code ended up being:

```
curl -X POST -H  "Authorization: JWT <token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
                 \"title\": \"Hello there\",
                     \"content\": \"high ground\",
                     \"schools\": "1",
                     \"course\": "1",
                     \"classes\": [
                         "1"
                     ],
                     \"isbn\": 12312,
                     \"semester\": "1",
                     \"visible\": true

 }' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/create/?type=post'
```

and then finally the output was:

```
{"title":"Hello there","content":"high ground","schools":1,"course":1,"classes":[1],"isbn":12312,"semester":1,"visible":true}
```

So be careful with the the request because you may end up getting the following error:

```
"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double-quotes"
```

or

```
"[globbing] nested brace in column"
```