# "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a project with Django Rest Framework and I ran into some problems and im not able to fix them.

So, I have a URL for post method and when I post there using postman, I get an error:

```
    {
  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"
}
```

This is the data im sending:

```
{username:"REQUAB", password:"REQUAB", emailId:"requab@gmail.com"}
```

And just to check if i had some problem in the serializer or the model, i did a normal get request and i got correct output.

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    emailId = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    recipes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'emailId', 'password', 'recipes']
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import UsersList, UsersDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('', UsersList.as_view()),
]
```

my views.py:

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from users.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

# Create your views here.

class UsersList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Pls help me with this (Thanks, in advance).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json parse error using POST in django rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114514/json-parse-error-using-post-in-django-rest-api)

Comment: What is your `request.data` returning?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to test my drf endpoint by posting json data to it. The solution was to wrap the json data with `json.dumps({...})`. For instance:

```py
import json

def test_webhook_endpoint_exists(self):
    response = self.client.post('/webhook/', json.dumps({"key": "value"}), content_type='application/json')
    self.assertNotEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, try to enclose the property names in double quotes or use `JSON.stringify` when sending it (using JS).

Comment: yes i thought of that but then i saw the drf documentation and there the code is same and i thought it is supposed to work. So am i missing something in the drf or just what u said?

Comment: @RishabRavi Do you have a link to the example you are referring to?

Comment: Only properly formatted JSON will be accepted.

Comment: ohk thanks i got my answer